# how to hide dropdown menu if we click outside the menu in vuejs

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using a `dropdown` menu components in vuejs to make normal dropdown menu. 
My code is for `dropdown` component is :

```
<template>
    <span class="dropdown" :class="{shown: state}">
        <a href="#" @click.prevent="toggleDropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">toggle menu</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" v-show="state">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <slot></slot>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </transition>
    </span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'dropdown',
    data () {
        return {
            state: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        toggleDropdown (e) {
            this.state = !this.state;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Now I am importing the `dropdown` component in my `VUE` app at various place by using following code in the template

```
<dropdown>
    <li>
         Action
    </li>
</dropdown>
```

Now that is working fine but I want that only one dropdown should be active at the same time.

I have done little research and found that i can use plugins like https://github.com/davidnotplay/vue-my-dropdown but I don't want to use that. Again i have also studied how the above example works but I want to implement this dropdown functionality in such a way that my `dropdown` component would take care of all event related to dropdown. **So can you help me how to achieve that?**

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I know it's quite an old question but I think the best way to do that without any external plugins is to add a click listener to mounted lifecycle hook (and remove it on beforeDestroy hook) and filter the clicks on your component so it only hides when clicked outside.

```
<template>
    <span class="dropdown" :class="{shown: state}">
      <a href="#" @click.prevent="toggleDropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">toggle menu</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" v-show="state">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <slot></slot>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <transition/>
    </span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'dropdown',
  data () {
    return {
      state: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleDropdown (e) {
      this.state = !this.state
    },
    close (e) {
      if (!this.$el.contains(e.target)) {
        this.state = false
      }
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    document.addEventListener('click', this.close)
  },
  beforeDestroy () {
    document.removeEventListener('click',this.close)
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I've used this approach before. It works well when put in a mixin or directive. The less plugins the better, esp when they are so simple.

Comment: such a great approach! thank you

Answer (score 3):

In Vue 3 the following should work

Note that the `@click.stop` on the dropdown trigger and on the dropdown content prevents the document event from executing the close function.

```js
<template>
  <div class="dropdown" :class="{'is-active': dropdown.active.value}">
    <div class="dropdown-trigger">
      <button class="button" @click.stop="dropdown.active.value = !dropdown.active.value">
        Toggle
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" role="filter">
      <div class="dropdown-content" @click.stop>
        <!-- dropdown items -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import { defineComponent, ref, onMounted, onBeforeUnmount } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Dropdown",
  setup(){
    const dropdown = {
      active: ref(false),
      close: () => {
        dropdown.active.value = false
      }
    }

    onBeforeUnmount(() => {
      document.removeEventListener('click', dropdown.close)
    })

    onMounted(() => {
      document.addEventListener('click', dropdown.close)
    })

    return {
      dropdown
    }
  }
})

</script>
```

This example uses `bulma` but off course you don't need to.

Comment: I wrote the codes in the style you said but it didn't work, is it possible to write code without making define Component?

Comment: @Liza Yes you can. In this example I use the Composition API. But you can also choose to use the Options API. You can find the difference here: https://vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html#api-styles

Comment: i run it normally but it didn't work for me

Comment: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-fixed-header-scroll-forked-bznu9n?file=/src/pages/Home.vue)
I added below but it didn't work

Comment: Your codesandbox works. It's the styling that is missing. Try changing `:class="{ 'is-active': dropdown.active.value }"` to `:style="{ 'display': (dropdown.active.value ? 'block' : 'none' }"`

Comment: [code new](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-fixed-header-scroll-forked-bznu9n?file=/src/pages/Home.vue)
 I did as you said but what a coincidence it doesn't work

Comment: Here is your codesandbox with the fix. You forgot to put the `.stop` after the toggle click. https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-fixed-header-scroll-forked-w7qz1b?file=/src/pages/Home.vue

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at vue-clickaway.([Link](https://github.com/simplesmiler/vue-clickaway))

> Sometimes you need to detect clicks outside of the element (to close a modal window or hide a dropdown select). There is no native event for that, and Vue.js does not cover you either. This is why vue-clickaway exists. Please check out the demo before reading further.

Comment: @Shubham it may solve the problem but i want to minimize the dependency  on any external component/plugin/resource . Anyways i will try to implement similar functionality, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `blur` event, e.g. if you add a method:

```
close() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.state = false;
    }, 200);
}
```

And set the `blur` event for your link:

```
<a href="#" @click.prevent="toggleDropdown" @blur="close">toggle menu</a>
```

Then the dropdown will get hidden whenever your toggle link loses focus.
The `setTimeout` is necessary because Javascript click events occur after blur, which would result in your dropdown links being not clickable. To work around this issue, delay the menu hiding a little bit.

Comment: Yup but this may not the perfect solution. Additionally we have to bind blur event to the parent wrapper i think because user may take some mili-seconds to select from the actions from dropdown