# How to close a dropdown list when clicking anywhere

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How do I close the dropdown that opens when I click anywhere?

This code:

```
<tr class="inputs-table">
  <td>Type object: </td>
  <td>
    <div class="select">
      <div class="select-header form-control" v-on:click="AddForm(1)">
        <span class="select__current">Please select one option</span>
      </div>
      <addForm v-if="addedForm === 1" />
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="inputs-table">
  <td>Type business-model: </td>
  <td>
    <div class="select">
      <div class="select-header form-control" v-on:click="AddForm(2)">
        <span class="select__current">Please select one option</span>
      </div>
      <addForm v-if="addedForm === 2" />
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

```
export default {
  name: 'Index',
  data() {
    return {
      addedForm: 0,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    AddForm(number) {
      this.addedForm = number;
    },
    closeForm() {
      this.addedForm = false;
    }
  },
  components: {
    addForm,
  }
}
```

Drop-list:

[image]

What can I try next?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to hide dropdown menu if we click outside the menu in vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46038989/how-to-hide-dropdown-menu-if-we-click-outside-the-menu-in-vuejs)

Comment: try this, `<div class="select-header form-control" v-on:click="AddForm(1)" v-on:blur="closeForm()">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<template>
  <div
    @click="dropdownIsActive = !dropdownIsActive"
    ref="dropdown"
  >
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      dropdownIsActive: false
    }),
    created () {
      window.addEventListener('click', this.closeDropdown)
    },
    methods: {
      closeDropdown (e) {
        if (!this.$refs.dropdown.contains(e.target)) {
          this.dropdownIsActive = false
        }
      }
    },
    beforeDestroy () {
      window.removeEventListener('click', this.closeDropdown)
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use if `window.onClick` and see whether or not it matches you'r element. If it doesn't then close it; call the function that checks clicks at mounted and beforeDestroy or breforeRouteLeave.

E.g:

```
mounted(){
    this.hideNav()
},
methods: {
    hideNav() {
        window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (!event.target.matches('.select__body')) {
            this.closeForm()
        }
     }
   }
},
beforeRouteLeave() {
    this.hideNav()
}
```

Comment: @АртёмСтоляр shoot my bad. answer updated, you needed to have `this.` before calling `hideNav`

Comment: heh, sorry and thank you, but still doesn't work and gives an error "this.closeForm is not a function at window.onclick"

Comment: maybe you know what's the matter

Comment: @АртёмСтоляр Replace `window.onclick = function(event)` with `window.addEventListener("click", function(event)` and see if it works

Comment: No, error again " TypeError: this.closeForm is not a function at eval"