# Vue js How to close the bootstrap dropdown menu when clicked outside the menu

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying close the dropdown menu when user clicks outside the dropdown menu

header_component.vue

```
<div class="dropdown d-inline-block">

    <a href="#" class="logo logo-dark">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="Logo-plus" @click="toggleMainMenu()">+</a>
        <span class="logo-lg">
            <img src="" alt="" height="25" id="topnav_heading_image">
        </span>
    </a>

    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" style="left: 0;right: auto;" v-bind:class="show_main_menu ? 'd-block' : ''">
        ..............
     </div>
 </div
```

what I tried is so far is adding addeventlistener to the body on click and removeEventListener the event on close.
Body Event is not triggered. How to add an event to body onclick?

```
    methods:{
        toggleMainMenu(){
            this.show_main_menu = !this.show_main_menu;
            this.show_sub_menu = false;
            this.setBodyClass();
        },
        openSubMenu(menu_key){

            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("access_token", window.settings.access_token);
            formData.append('menu_key',menu_key);

            this.show_main_menu = false;
            axios.post('/api/get_sub_menus', formData).then((response) => {
                
                if(response.is_sub_menu == 0){                        
                    window.location.href = response.route;
                }else{                        
                    
                    this.sub_menus = _.chunk(_.toArray(response.data.sub_menu), 3);
                    this.show_sub_menu = true;
                }

            });

        },
        setBodyClass() {
            var body = document.body;
            body.classList.toggle('open');
            if(this.show_main_menu){
                body.addEventListener('click', e => {
                this.toggleMainMenu;
              });
            } else {
                body.removeEventListener('click', e => {
                console.log('closed');
              });
            }
        }
       
    },

    directives: {
    "my-directive": {
      bind: function(el, binding) {
        alert('hello');
        this.el.addEventListener('click', e => {
            this.toggleMainMenu;
          });
      },
      unbind: function(el) {
        // Remove Event Listener
       this.el.removeEventListener('click', e => {
                console.log('closed');
        });
      }
    }
```

[image]

I tried with directives as well it does not work

```
<body class="container-fluid p-0" v-my-directive="1">\
<body
```

Comment: Bootstrap dropdowns seem to already have that feature, does it not work? Btw `<"/div>` is faulty

Comment: typo I have corrected. But issue not solved. No it  does not work

Comment: Hm, aren't nested links invalid?!

Comment: Please help I tired every method

Comment: I found the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46038989/how-to-hide-dropdown-menu-if-we-click-outside-the-menu-in-vuejs

Comment: I don't see any `class="dropdown-toggle"` or `data-toggle="dropdown"` in your code, how do you use that dropdown?

Comment: bind class is used to show the dropdown menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code as solved my problem

```
    mounted(){
        document.addEventListener('click', this.close);
    },
    methods:{
        toggleMainMenu(){
            this.show_main_menu = !this.show_main_menu;
            this.show_sub_menu = false;
        },
        openSubMenu(menu_key){

            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("access_token", window.settings.access_token);
            formData.append('menu_key',menu_key);

            this.show_main_menu = false;
            axios.post('/api/get_sub_menus', formData).then((response) => {
                
                if(response.is_sub_menu == 0){                        
                    window.location.href = response.route;
                }else{                        
                    
                    this.sub_menus = _.chunk(_.toArray(response.data.sub_menu), 3);
                    this.show_sub_menu = true;
                }

            });

        },
        close (e) {
          if (!this.$el.contains(e.target)) {
            this.show_main_menu = false;
          }
        }            
       
    },
    beforeDestroy () {
        document.removeEventListener('click',this.close);
    },
```